# Class "ZipArchive" not found in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I hosted a laravel website in hostinger vps. I used import export lib in that laravel website. So while importing a file I am getting this error:

```
Class "ZipArchive" not found
```

I tried to intall

```
apt-get install php-zip
systemctl apache2 restart
```

Currently I am using php 8.1. After trying still getting this error. Is there a way to solve this issue? Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `ZipArchive` is a package that was installed with `composer`. If you cannot run `composer install` on hostinger, you'll have to upload your vendor directory.

Comment: try to use the explicit php version e.g. `apt-get install php8.1-zip` sometimes the default version that is used by the package manger is different

Comment: after doing following you I am getting Call to undefined function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\simplexml_load_string()

this error @apokryfos

Comment: That's progress. It now indicates you need `php8.1-xml`